# Browser JavaScript Implications of `delete window.eval`?

Tags: javascript, browser, eval

In the browser, JavaScript usage of `eval` is often cited as being "evil."  Nicholas C. Zakas makes the case that  [eval() isn’t evil, just misunderstood](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/) and covers the Debugability, Performance and Security topics. The Google Chrome [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) document mentions the default policy disables `eval` and requires and requires you to add `'unsafe-eval'` to reenable .

As a test case, I ran the following from the Chrome developer tools JavaScript console. to see what happens when I `delete window.eval`

```
> eval("1+1")
  2
> window.eval("1+1")
  2
> delete window.eval
  true
> eval("1+1")
  ReferenceError: eval is not defined
> window.eval("1+1")
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Other that potentially enhancing security and breaking third party code that relies on `eval`, what are the other implications of executing `delete window.eval` ?

Comment: I know jQuery uses `eval` internally, but you said other than 3rd-party code.

Comment: Mr Zakas is correct that `eval()` is not evil. Do all browsers allow you to delete `window.eval`? In my copy of IE11 it seems to break the console. Why do you want to delete `eval()`? Why do you think it enhances security to do so, given that a script that did so would only affect the current page?

Comment: @nnnnnn - Chrome lets you delete it, even in safe mode: `(function() {"use strict"; delete window.eval; console.log(typeof window.eval); console.log(window.eval) })();`

Comment: there are a lot of ways to break your browser if you so choose. how breaking your own page provides security, i don't quite get. besides, there's several other ways to run a string as code besides eval(). in "use strict", you can make eval() safe: it's Function() that you still need to disable...

Comment: not asserting this is a good idea, just noticed that Content-Security-Policy can prevent eval, so investigating implications of deleting eval to the same end result.